# Troubles on user defined type in array using julia

Tags: julia

I have some troubles using array containing user-defined type.
A simple code goes like this:

```
struct MyType
 a::Int64
 b::Int64
end

MyArray = Array{MyType}(5)
MyArray[1].a = [1 2 3]
```

The compiler shows an error message 
"UnderRefError: access to undefined reference"
Is this the problem due to there is no default constructor for MyType?

Answer (score 4):

In fact, there is always a default inner constructor automatically defined by Julia if you don't explicitly define one. It's equivalent to :

```
julia> struct MyType
         a::Int64
         b::Int64
         MyType(a,b) = new(a,b)
       end
```

Note that, by running `MyArray = Array{MyType}(5)`, you just construct an 5-element array whose `eltype` should be `MyType`. Julia still doesn't know what on earth those entries are, that's what the error is complaining about.
Take a look at the following example:

```
julia> a = Array{Complex}(5)
5-element Array{Complex{T<:Real},1}:
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
```

btw, I don't know what you mean to do with this line `MyArray[1].a = [1 2 3]`, since `a` is of type `Int`, not `Vector{Int}`.

Answer (score 3):

This line doesn't make sense

```
MyArray[1].a = [1 2 3]
```

You got to write something like

```
MyArray[1] = MyType(4, 5)
```

because the first element of the `MyArray` array isn't defined. `MyArray[1].a` means you are trying to access the `a` member of an undefined object. That isn't going to work.

If you want to create an initialized 5 element array of MyType objects you can do something like this instead.

```
fill(MyType(0, 0), 10)
```